# hide paging numbers in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to hide paging numbers on gridview that shows on bottom of the gridview. I am using dropdown list instead of this number clicks. How can I hide them?

Please advice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pagersettings.visible.aspx), it's as simple as:

```
GridView.PagerSettings.Visible = false;
```

Comment: It does not work. It hides the entire Pager row. What the OP wants is a way to hide the controls inside the Pager row, which are the page numbers and any other left and right controls.

Answer (score 2):

You should add this code:

```
GridView1.BottomPagerRow.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the `<PagerTemplate>` of the Gridview to modify it however you wish.