# How to hide the paging row in the gridview when exporting in excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I am using a gridview and paging is added to it.. when exporting in the excel i dont want the paging numbers 1 2 3..

```
<asp:GridView ID="mygrid" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="mygrid_Sorting"
            AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="Gridview" OnPageIndexChanging="mygrid_PageIndexChanging">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName"
                    HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">                 
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AvailableQuantity" HeaderText="AvailableQuantity" SortExpression="AvailableQuantity"
                    HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductId" HeaderText="ProductId" SortExpression="ProductId"
                    HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
                </asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Export Data to Excel" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
```

the above grid allows paging and 1 2 3 are the page numbers.. when exporting to excel it is showing the paging numbers.. how to remove the paging numbers in excel

Comment: Try this link. It wiil be helpful for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405871/hide-paging-numbers-in-gridview

Comment: mygrid.PagerSettings.Visible = false; i added but still its showing the pagingnumbers

Comment: Refer this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pagersettings.visible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Before rendering - disable the paging, bind the data and then render:

```
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
GridView1.DataSource = ds; //Data Source
GridView1.DataBind();
GridView1.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter)
```